# How to disable indexing of attachments in solr 3.6.2

Tags: solr

I'm using solr 3.6.2. How to disable indexing of attachments in solr 3.6.2. My schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="50" side="back" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" types="myTypes.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" types="myTypes.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>

<copyField source="body" dest="an_text" maxChars="128000"/>
<field name="an_text"   type="text"   indexed="true" stored="false" />

<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!--<tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>-->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" types="myTypes.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

My file myTypes.txt:

```
% => DIGIT
- => DIGIT
```

When I build the index, attachments also indexed. I would like to disable the index build attachments.

Comment: What do you mean by attachments? Looks more like a client problem then a Solr issue.

Comment: Solr builds an index of e-mails on the mail server. Emails contain attachments. How to disable indexing of attachments?

Comment: This should be handled in the application that is sending the emails to Solr.